# existence and uniqueness of solutions for nonlinear 2nd order ode with Cauchy boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

What are the known results on the existence and uniqueness of solutions for nonlinear second order ordinary differential equations with Cauchy boundary conditions?

Answer (score 4):

You can always "unroll" an ODE involving higher-order derivatives into a system involving only first-order derivatives. After having done so, it is possible to apply the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for existence and uniqueness (see also the [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) for existence *without* uniqueness).

For example, consider the nonlinear second order ODE
$$
y^{\prime\prime}(t)=f(t,y(t),y^{\prime}(t)).
$$
Let $z(t)=y^{\prime}(t)$ so that $z^{\prime}(t)=y^{\prime\prime}(t)$. Then, the ODE can be rewritten as the system
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}(t) & =z(t);\\
z^{\prime}(t) & =f(t,y(t),z(t)).
\end{align*}
Letting $x(t)=(y(t),z(t))$, we can put this into the familiar form
$$
x(t)=f(t,x(t))
$$
and apply Picard-Lindelöf (or Peano).

Comment: So, if I understood correctly this theorem will work if I have initial conditions, what if I have boundary conditions?

Comment: I don't think a trivial modification of the above would work in the case of boundary value problem $y(a)=y_a$ and $y(b)=y_b$. Some googling did reveal a few papers of interest, however:
Jackson, Lloyd K. "Subfunctions and second-order ordinary differential inequalities." Advances in Mathematics 2.3 (1968): 307-363.
Lasota, A., and Zn Opial. "On the existence and uniqueness of solutions of a boundary value problem for an ordinary second-order differential equation." Colloquium Mathematicae. Vol. 18. No. 1. Institute of Mathematics Polish Academy of Sciences, 1967.