# Existence and uniqueness of $y''(t)=\tan(y(t))+\sqrt[3]{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ODE: $$y''(t)=\tan(y(t))+\sqrt[3]{t}$$

I need to determine for which initial condition there exists a solution, and if it is unique.

Can I solve the problem using the existence and uniqueness theorem for first order ODE? I haven't leanred about higher order ODE yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call $\dot{y}(t)=z(t)$ and so $\ddot{y}(t)=\dot z(t)$. Then, consider now that you have a system of first order ODEs, or that your unknown function is two dimensional, by calling it $\vec x(t)=\big(y(t), z(t)\big)$. You can also apply the theorem here, but remember that your initial condition has two values for a given $t_0$: $y(t_0)$ and $z(t_0)=\dot y(t_0)$.

In this case, you would have$$\dot{\vec x}(t)=F\big(t, \vec x(t)\big),$$where $\dot{\vec x}(t)=\big(\dot y(t), \dot z(t)\big)$ and
$$F\big(t, \vec x\big)=F\big(t,y,z\big)=\big(z,\tan (y)+\sqrt[3]t\big).$$
Where is it continuous in $t$ (or where not)? Where is it Lipschitz in $\vec x$?

More information in this answer and many others in this website:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1664979/481187

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see $F$ is continuous anywhere but $y=\pi/2+\pi k$, so there exists a solution in that domain. For uniqueness, I learned it is enough to check if the derivative of $F$ in respect to $\vec x$ is continuous. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You actually need to check if it's bounded in the interval $[t_0,T]$ (or the same backwards). But continuity is enough for that to happen. If the derivative is bounded at a point $\vec x_0$ and $F$ is continuous in $t=t_0$, then there is a unique solution for the initial condition $\vec x(t_0)=\vec x_0$ (this sets both the position and the velocity, in physical terms). The condition that $F$ be Lipschitz is more general and also guarantees uniqueness: if the derivative is continuous then $F$ is Lipschitz, but the reciprocal might not be true. Anyway, that'll be enough for most situations.

Comment: Also, remember that the derivative here is a $2\times2$ matrix $DF$ with the derivatives of each component w.r.t. each variable.

Comment: Thanks! so if my calculations are correct, in the domain $y \neq \pi /2 + \pi k$ there exists a unique solution?

Comment: Yes. Note that this means than there exists a unique solution for any initial condition$$y(t_0)=y_0,\quad y'(t_0)=v_0$$
with $t_0,y_0,v_0\in\mathbb R$, $y_0\neq \tfrac\pi2+k\pi, \forall k\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply the theory of first order ODEs as soon as you have rewritten your equation. See here [How to reduce higher order linear ODE to a system of first order ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501745/how-to-reduce-higher-order-linear-ode-to-a-system-of-first-order-ode) how to do it.